# HTML5 <VIDEO> Embed Issue

Tags: html, video, embed

I have created a very simple  embed with fall-back code for all browsers.  When test viewing in FF4 locally, the video appears and plays perfectly. But when I upload to a remote server (retaining the same file structure) the video does not appear. All other browsers seem to be displaying fine...  You can see it here: http://www.selfdestruct.tv/h5/

Why?

Comment: Video in HTML5 is hell.... :( please take a look at http://mediaelementjs.com/

Answer (score 4):

Check your server and make sure that the mime types are defined for these video types. Not serving proper mime types with the file can stop many browsers from playing videos properly, the type attribute is simply not enough.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html#video-mime-types is an excellent resource on HTML 5 video.

Answer (score 0):

Besides mime types above, also check video file permissions.